# How would I select this element using Selenium in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selector, classname

I am trying to select for the value 1352 in Java Selenium on ChromeDriver

```
<span class="numfound" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1522936314968_15">1352</span>
```

Because the id is nonintuitive, I'd like to select using the String "numfound". I've tried selecting byClassName("numfound") and this was returned:

```
<[[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (befee42078624a3b036869cf2a4a0c14)] -> class name: numfound]>
```

Alternatively, I've tried to select by CSS and got this:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#resultsnum span.numfound"}
```

Perhaps my selector for CSS was wrong? What would be the most intuitive way to select this element using numfound?

RESOLVED: I was silly and didn't use .getText() for what I wanted.

Comment: Can you show actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the By-selector only for elements inside of the tag.

To get the text of an element

1. you can use

   `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='numfound']")).getText();`

   or (if you like more):

   `driver.findElement(By.className("numfound")).getText();`
2. or get it from the page source by

   `String source = driver.getPageSource();`

and extract a string from this, starting with "numfound" and ending with following  tag
Then extract your string from this line.

Comment: Ahhh, I've forgot to use .getText(). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This span is a WebElement. There are certain things that you can do with WebElement. Some of those are :

```
    1. click on it. (Provided that element must be clickable)
    2. getText() : Text between the <span> and </span> tag.
    3. getSize();
    4. getLocation();
    5. getScreenShotAs(OUTPUT.Type)
    6. getRect();
    7. SendKeys(charSequence)  (Provided that it can take input something).
```

and many more.

As of now, in your problem, you can get the text between span tag.
by using this code :

```
String spanText = driver.findElement(by.cssSelector("span[class="numfound"]")).getText();
```

and do String operations on it.
Let me know if you have any concerns about this.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do:

```
WebElement element = browser.findElement(By.className("numfound"));
//do whatever you want with your element, get attributes, etc.
```

For reference: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-class-name